# Why Python doesn't iterate over repeated list into one list

Tags: python-2.7

Right now I'm working on Python 2.7 and I have a little issue.

I explain I need to get the index of a list that is into another list:

```
students=[["A","B"],["A","B"]]

for m in students:
    if "A" in m and "B" in m:
        print m
```

When I run this code I got this:

```
['A', 'B']
['A', 'B']
```

It seems to be right, it iterates over students and print twice ['A', 'B'] because it's repeated...but if I run this code:

```
for m in students:
    if "A" in m and "B" in m:
        print students.index(m)
```

it prints this:

```
0
0
```

It seems that it only iterates over the first element, for me the correct output should be like this:

```
0
1
```

Could anyone explain me why Python do that, and how to fix it, Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`students.index(m)` returns the *first* index, `i`, where `students[i]` equals `m`.

Since `students` contains the same item twice, 0 is returned both times.

So the loop is iterating over both items in `students`, but since `student[0] == student[1]`, when `m` is bound to `students[1]`, `students.index(student[1]))` still returns 0.

---

If you simply want to report the *current index of the loop*, then use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
students = [["A","B"],["A","B"]]
for i, m in enumerate(students):
    if "A" in m and "B" in m:
        print i
```

prints

```
0
1
```